# php how to generate dynamic list()?

Tags: php, list, variables, extract

base on my understanding, this how list() work.

```
list($A1,$A2,$A3) = array($B1,B2,B3);
```

So with the help of `list()` we can assign value out from array accordingly.
here is my question... **how to generate a dynamic list()?**

1). base on database return result, I'm not sure how many of it but I assign it all into array
2). so we can use count(array) to know how many of it.
3). so then **HOW CAN I GENERATE/PREPARE** a list for it?

Example: client A, have 3 kids, name Apple, Boy, Cat
so I use `list($kid1, $kid2, $kid3)` for it.

but when client B, have more then 3 kids, I only get first 3
or if client C, have only 1 kids, then error encounter.

I know if base on the situation above, there is many way to solve it without using `list()`
but I wish to know or find out the solution with using `list()`.

**How to generate dynamic `list()` base on count of `array()`**

thanks guys/gals

Comment: Why would you want to use `list`? Why not simply access them by their index? There seems to be no gain by using `list` in this case...

Comment: @JosephSilber `i know if base on the situation above, there is many way to solve it without using list() but i wish to know or find out the solution with using list().` from question

Comment: Joseph, he did state why: curiosity

Comment: You can use `extract()` on the array, to create variables inside the current scope...

Comment: @LoSauer - That only works on an associative array.

Comment: `list()` should extremely rarely be used in my opinion.  It tends to lead to things like `for ($i = 0; $i < $k; ++$i) { echo ${'var' . $i}; }`.  What happens when you want to loop over all of `$kid1`, `$kid2`, etc?

Comment: ok, i will try extract() later, thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you have a variable number of elements, use *arrays* for them! It does not make sense to extract them into individual variables if you do not know how many variables you'll be dealing with. Say you did extract those values into variables `$kid1` through `$kidN`, what is the code following this going to do? You have no idea how many variables there are in the scope now, and you have no practical method of finding out or iterating them next to testing whether `$kid1` through `$kidN` are `isset` or not. That's insane use of variables. Just use arrays.

Having said that, [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $varname = 'kid' . $i++;
    $$varname = $value;
}
```

Comment: +1 for *That's insane use of variables*. And of course it's a simple and readable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a lambda expression with [create_function()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) for this. The list() will be only accessible within the expression.

Answer (score 0):

This is not what PHP's `list` is meant for. From the official [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

```
list is not really a function, but a language construct. 
list() is used to assign a list of variables in one operation.
```

In other words, the compiler does not actually invoke a function but directly compiles your code into allocations for variables and assignment.

- You can specifically skip to a given element, by setting commas as follows:

  `list($var1, , $var2) = Array($B1, B2, B3);`

  `echo "$var1 is before $var2 \n";`
- or take the third element

  `list( , , $var3) = Array($B1, B2, B3);`

(I am assuming B2, B3 are constants? Or are you missing a `$`?)

Specifically using `list`, you can use PHP's `variable variables` to create variables from an arbitrary one-dimensional array as follows:

```
$arr = array("arrindex0" => "apple", "banana", "pear");
reset($arr);
while (list($key, $val) = each($arr)) {
    $key = is_numeric($key) ? "someprefix_" . $key : $key;
    echo "key sdf: $key <br />\n";
    $$key = $val;
}
var_dump($arrindex0, $someprefix_0, $someprefix_1);
```

Result

```
string 'apple' (length=5)
string 'banana' (length=6)
string 'pear' (length=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

This creates variables `$A1, $A2, .... $AN` for each element in your array:

```
$list =  array("a", "b", "c", "d");

extract(array_combine(array_map(function($i) {
        return "A" . $i;
    }, range(1, count($list))), $list));

echo implode(" ", array($A1, $A2, $A3, $A4)), PHP_EOL;
```

You can modify the name of the variables in the `array_map` callback. I hope I'll never see code like that in production ;)