# Split array using list and array_chunk for dynamic requirements

Tags: php

I am using list and array_chunk to split arrays.  In my first example I split the array into four pieces using list.

I would like to change the number from 4 to say 8 and have it dynamically do this. Instead of manually creating it in the code. Is this possible ? I assume I could use variable naming as listed in my non working second example below.

How it works now :

```
list($inv0, $inv1, $inv2, $inv3) = array_chunk($val['inventory'], ceil(count($val['inventory']) / 4));
```

What I would like is to set something $i = 8 and have it automatically split into 8 chunks dynamically .

Something like :

```
$i = 8
list(${inv.0}, ${inv.1}, ${inv.2}, ${inv.3},${inv.4},${inv.5},${inv.6},${inv.7}) = array_chunk($val['inventory'], ceil(count($val['inventory']) / $i));
```

So based on my needs I can split the array into X pieces instead of hard coding it to 4 or 8 etc...

Comment: Any time you find yourself creating dynamic variable names you should be using an array instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `foreach` to create the variables you want:

```
$array = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'];
$chunk = array_chunk($array,2);

foreach($chunk as $i => $data) {
    ${'inv'.$i} = $data;
}

print_r($inv0);
print_r($inv1);

die();
```

Output

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b )
Array ( [0] => c [1] => d )
```

Answer (score 1):

There are ways, but I don't think it'd be a maintainable approach since you don't even know how many variables you'd need to process. 
However, Felipe Duarte provides a working answer and there are some more over here : [php how to generate dynamic list()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550154/php-how-to-generate-dynamic-list)

But I'd agree with the top answer.
`array_chunk` already provides you with pretty much what you are looking for:

```
$chunks = array_chunk($val['inventory'], ceil(count($val['inventory']) / $i));
print_r($chunks); 
// [[0] => ['', ''], [1] => ['','']...]
```

You can then access it via the indices (such as `$chunks[0]`, `$chunks[1]`).

Comment: You both have great answers, I overlooked the fact that I don't even need list, I think I am using it because I copied from another piece of my code, thank you for the advice.